# Закрытие doc файла по заголовку

Tags: bat, cmd

Всем привет. 
Как закрыть .doc файл с названием example.doc, используя команду taskkill?

Такая команда не работает :(
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq example.DOC" /im winword.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`taskkill` с такой задачей не справится, так как для открытия документа обычно не создается отдельный процесс. Убивать `winword.exe` нельзя. Закрыть документ поможет `vbscript`

```
On Error Resume Next 'без генерации исключений'
Dim W
If WScript.Arguments.Count Then Stop  'название документа передаем через аргументы'
Set W=GetObject(,"Word.Application")  'подключаемся к Word'
If Err<>0 Then Stop                   
W.Documents(WScript.Arguments(0)).Close 'закрываем'
```

Сохранить в `%скрипт%.vbs`, вызывать `%скрипт%.vbs %название документа%`

[Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171848(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Скрипт работает. 
Появилось 2 вопроса - как сделать так, чтобы автоматически сохранялись изменения перед закрытием, а также - в случае,когда в ворде открыт только этот документ, выключался и сам ворд?

Comment: В ответе ссылка - там все ответы.